# Drag and Drop textblocks from stackpanels to a canvas

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a grid divided into 3 columns. The first contain a StackPanel, the second contain a Canvas and than a StackPanel again. When my window is loaded the stackpanels are populated with textblocks. How can I make these textblocks be drag and drop onto the canvas?

I tried using mouseDown and mouseMove events but failed...

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="StackDragDrop.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1000">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="APanel" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Canvas Name="MyCanvas" Grid.Column="1" AllowDrop="True"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="BPanel" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            TextBlock Block = new TextBlock();
            Block.FontSize = 25;
            Block.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
            Block.MouseMove += Block_MouseMove;
            APanel.Children.Add(Block);
        }
        for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
        {
            TextBlock Block = new TextBlock();
            Block.FontSize = 25;
            Block.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
            Block.MouseMove += Block_MouseMove;
            BPanel.Children.Add(Block);
        }
    }

    void Block_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop((sender as TextBlock).Parent, sender, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your current code and XAML.

Comment: I found [this blog post by Bea Stollnitz](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488#.UzBqHKuHet8) very useful for setting up dragging/dropping between two databound controls. I even used it (with some modifications) for the exact same scenario you have - dragging items between a `StackPanel` and a `Canvas`, although in my case my StackPanel was floating on top of my Canvas instead of being next to it